# Grid layout with each element taking up only the space it needs

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I currently have this picture shown:

[image]

It is made by:

```
.gallery-grid {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
 }
```

I've looked and it seems to not be possible to have each element only take up the space it needs instead of the height of the highest image? I've tried setting `grid-auto-rows` to `auto` and that does not change anything.

Any alternative solution to `grid` is fine also. I've tried `flexbox` and setting the `flex-basis` but can't seem to get that working either.

Comment: What do you WANT it to look like? Do you want the images to all move upwards as much as possible so there is no whitespace?

Comment: Yes, I would like the elements to only take up the space of their image instead of the entire height of the tallest element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/3597276

Comment: Obviously this is **not** an actual *grid* is it?.....It's just columns and without rows...it's not a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy answer that doesn't require either grid or flexbox:

I simply set `.gallery-grid` to have `column-width: 300px`

[image]